# CSS body width not scaled to phone width

Tags: html, css

I'm testing basic layout:

```
<html>
    <head>
         <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./../public/css/main.css"> 
    </head>
    <body>
    </body> 
</html>
```

And there is style of body element

```
 background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
 color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
 display: block;
 font-family: 'Segoe UI', Ubuntu, Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 height: 1091px;
 line-height: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 min-height: 100%;
 min-width: 1024px;
 padding-bottom: 0px;
 padding-left: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 padding-top: 0px;
 width: 1024px;
```

The thing is that I was sure that body width will be scaled and fitted to the phone size. But when I tested on iPhone 3GS horizontal scrollbar appeared. Why width is not scaled?

Comment: why dont you use margin:0; and padding:0;? Less code..

Comment: Add the following meta tag to your head `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">`

Answer (score 0):

Add the below to your head:

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1' name='viewport' />
```

Comment: that would prevent the user from being able to zoom. Probably not what the OP wants on a 1024px wide page

Comment: The OP didn't mention this, just that on certain devices the scrollbar appears.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following meta tag to the head of your document:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are defining :

```
 min-width: 1024px;
 width: 1024px;
```

You should remove both, and define the meta :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Comment: Adding of <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> will make width of page equal to 320px. But this is not what I want. I want page has minimum width of 1024px and I want page to be resized to fit mobile screen (like zoom out). I would like to know is it possible? :)

Comment: @Tamara Sorry, I don't get it... If you want it to render as it's zoomed out with its original size, don't use the viewport meta (?)